In js2-mode, how can I insert another star after creating a new line in comment?
For example, | is the location of the cursor.
/*
 * This is a comment|
 */

Now I type Enter. I would prefer the screen becomes:
/*
 * This is a comment
 * |
 */

But in reality it is
/*
 * This is a comment
 |

How can I achieve the preferred screen in js2-mode?

Type M-j (bound to default-indent-new-line whose doc string says: Break line at point and indent. If a comment syntax is defined, call ‘comment-line-break-function’. ).

Type M-j, bound to default-indent-new-line whose doc string says:
Break line at point and indent.
If a comment syntax is defined, call ‘comment-line-break-function’.

That should work in most programming modes.
